# What are the differences in functionality between these two code versions using GPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

##### Overview

I have 2 codes to move a 4-phase step motor over an A4988 driver and raspberry pi but only the code version with class elements (code 2) works without fails. My question is why?

##### What's the problem?

If I start the code without classes (code 1), the motor rotates first as it has to do. All works like a charm, but if the job is done and the code execution finished, the motor starts moving asymetric again. Ghostwalk or how ever it is called. After that I have to start code 2 and finishing over CTRL + C to stop that ghostwalk. Also if I wait to see if the motor starts again after the CTRL + C, the motor doesn't. All great again.  I have also that warning:

> RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.

Which looks to me that something is wrong with that GPIO stuff.  Both codes throw that warning message, but only code 2 has no issues after finishing the job. Why? Do I do something wrong with code 1? Do classes have some security stuff included which code 1 does not have? If yes can you give me please a small example to figure it out how to solve it over code 1?

##### Code 1

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time, json, sys

DIR_PIN = 17; STEP_PIN = 18; steps = 200
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(DIR_PIN, GPIO.OUT);  GPIO.setup(STEP_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(DIR_PIN, GPIO.LOW); GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
speed = 200
forward = steps >= 0
GPIO.output(DIR_PIN, GPIO.HIGH if forward else GPIO.LOW)
time_per_step = 1.0 / speed
for count in range(abs( steps )):
  GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
  GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(time_per_step)
GPIO.output(DIR_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, GPIO.LOW)      
GPIO.cleanup()
```

##### Code 2

```
DIR_PIN = 17
STEP_PIN = 18
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(DIR_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(STEP_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

class A4988:
  def __init__(self, DIR=DIR_PIN, STEP=STEP_PIN):
    self._dir = DIR
    self._step = STEP
    GPIO.output(self._dir, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(self._step, GPIO.LOW)

  def move_sync(self, steps, speed=1000.0):
    forward = steps >= 0
    GPIO.output(self._dir, GPIO.HIGH if forward else GPIO.LOW)
    time_per_step = 1.0 / speed
    for count in range(abs(steps)):
      GPIO.output(self._step, GPIO.HIGH)
      GPIO.output(self._step, GPIO.LOW)
      time.sleep(time_per_step)

   def deinit(self):
     GPIO.cleanup()
     self._dir = None
     self._step = None

   def __enter__(self): return self
   def __exit__(self): self.deinit() 

stepper = A4988()
speed = 200
stepper.move_sync(200, speed)
time.sleep(1.0)
stepper.move_sync(-200, speed)
time.sleep(1.0)
```

##### What I tried

```
GPIO.output(DIR_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, GPIO.LOW)      
print("Start des Schrittmotor-Tests.")
move_sync(200, speed)
move_sync(-200, speed)
DIR_PIN = None
STEP_PIN = None
atexit.register(GPIO.cleanup())
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Code 2 does not call `GPIO.cleanup()` at the end, and it does not change the "dir" pin back to low at the end if it has been high for the last movement.